# Jquery mousemove() gets activated without a mouse movement

Tags: jquery, fadeout, mousemove

I am trying to do a google.com like fade in (Cept i want to fade out text)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("html").mousemove(function () {
      $("p").fadeOut("slow");
    });
  });
</script>
```

With that code, my fade out gets automatically activated although I have not moved the mouse. Happens in all browsers. Any tips?

Comment: Can't reproduce in Chrome 5, FF 3.6.

Comment: here's an example http://www.ximnet.com.my/jquery/mousemove.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the event fires once initially and `mousemove` fires every time you move it a pixel, you could just ignore the very first (possibly automatic, depending on browser) `mousemove` event to get the effect you want, like this:

```
$(function() {
  var moveCount = 0;
  $("html").mousemove(function () {
    if(moveCount++ === 0) return; //first run?
    $("p").fadeOut("slow");
    $(this).unbind('mousemove'); //unbind this, no need to stick around
  });
});​
```

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rS9ey/7/), all we're doing is ignoring the *very* first firing of the `mousemove` event, after that we do the fade and unbind this handler so that it doesn't run for future `mousemove` firings, just cleaning up.

Comment: I know for certain that Firefox (3.x at least) does *NOT* fire off an automatic mousemove event.  As, there were times when I wondered why the Google search page hadn't performed the fade-in.  It was, of course, because I hadn't moved the mouse.  Any browser that does needs to be fixed, because that's just unexpected and strange behavior.

Comment: Cool nick! That works. 
Strangly though in chrome if the mouse is laying in the website area (not moved) it activates. Firefox and IE work ok. No big deal. Thanks again (**wishes he could give plus one!)

@George Marian I am not the only one with problem check out http://forum.jquery.com/topic/mousemove-strange-behavior-in-ie Are you sure google uses jquery for their fade?

Comment: No, they don't use jQuery: onmousemove="google&&google.fade&&google.fade(event)" .... Any idea what about jQuery or maybe the various ways to hook into events that's causing this?

Comment: I've also noticed that Flash objects, and changing tabs fire mousemove events which I cannot really explain.

Comment: In my case (Google Chrome), moveCount was climbing to 3 with no mouse move on my side at all. I had thus to set a thresshold on 5 to actually 'listen' to mousemove.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that if the page loads and the mouse is present on the page once the page has loaded it will fire an event. Try hiding your mouse from the page by leaving it over the address bar or somewhere over the menu at the top of your browser, refresh the page with F5 and notice that the event is not fired. Similarly, try refreshing with F5 and immediately right click on the page. Keep your mouse over the page but make sure that the context menu is still open. Once the page has loaded, without moving your mouse at all, hit the Escape key on your keyboard so the mouse will exit the context menu and return to the page. The mouse has not moved but has been detected on the page and the event is triggered.

Tested in Chrome 5 on Windows 7. Too lazy to try another browser but I assume it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is not 'micro movements'? Sometimes an optical mouse can causes movements to register just with dust or dirt.

Comment: Good point, but I dont have the problem with other situations (For example google.com)