# Javascript/jQuery - trigger action only when mouse moves

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to trigger an action only once when user moves the mouse slightly and it doesn't matter on what part of the page. If the mouse doesn't move, action shouldn't be triggered. When mouse moves (could be 3 minutes after the page is completely loaded), then the action should take place only once.

This is what I have right now:

```
  $(document).one('mousemove', function() {
    $('.front #main .block-content').animate({opacity : 0.3}, 200);
  });
```

The problem is immediately after the page is completely loaded, the animation will be triggered, no matter what I do with the mouse (stopped or moving).

I hope I was clear enough, but I can try to clarify further if this isn't enough. Is there a solution for this I am trying to achieve?

Thank you.

Comment: the problem could the queueing of events

Comment: Here you go :) Same issue (and resolution) over here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129148/jquery-mousemove-gets-activated-without-a-mouse-movement

Comment: @ArunPJohny Seems a mousemove event is triggered on pageload?

Comment: Thank you, Darren, the solution you pointed to me solves the problem. But I had to adapt it. I have done a console.log to count the number of times the mousemove is triggered on page load and it reached the count of 3. I have this set a tresshold on 5 to start taking the mouse move action. Maybe there is a better solution, but this is working. If you want to post is as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @MarcosBuarque - i wont bother putting an answer - i'd only be copy/pasting :) - perhaps put an **Edit** in your answer with a link to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$(document).mousemove(function(){
 $('.front #main .block-content').animate({opacity : 0.3}, 200);
})
```

instead

Comment: Thanks, masoud, but this doesn't solve the problem. The solution that solves my problem specifically was pointed by Darren as a comment under my post.